# ElasticSearch Field boosting using java api

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I am new to ES and trying to search using java apis. I am unable to figure out how I can provide filed specific boosting using the java apis.
Here is the example:
My index document looks like:

_source": {

```
"th_id": 1,
"th_name": "test name",
"th_description": "test desc",
"th_image": "test-img",
"th_slug": "Make-Me-Smart",
"th_show_title": "Coast Tech Podcast",
"th_sh_category": "Alternative Health
```

}

When i search for keywords I want to boost the results higher if they found in the "th_name" compared to they're found in some other fields.
Currently I am using below code to do search:

```
QueryBuilder qb1 = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(keyword, "th_name", "th_description", "th_show_title", "th_sh_category");
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("talk").setTypes("themes")
        .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH).setQuery(qb1)
        .setFrom(start).setSize(maxRows)
        .setExplain(true).execute().actionGet();
```

Is there anything I can do at query time to boost the document if the keyword is found in "th_name" field compared to found in other fields?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: This has changed and does no longer work in ES 6.x and upwards.

You should also be able to boost a field directly in the Multi-match query:

"The multi_match query supports field boosting via ^ notation in the fields json field.

```
{
  "multi_match" : {
    "query" : "this is a test",
    "fields" : [ "subject^2", "message" ]
  } 
}
```

In the above example hits in the subject field are 2 times more important than in the message field."

In the java-api, just use the MultiMatchQueryBuilder:

```
MultiMatchQueryBuilder builder = 
new MultiMatchQueryBuilder( keyword, "th_name^2", "th_description", "th_show_title", "th_sh_category" );
```

Disclaimer: Not tested

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for providing the java version too.

Comment: This will give exception as things finally boils down to : 
 "fields": [ "subject^1.0^2","message^1.0" ]

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer did not work me. ES version I am using is `6.2.4`.

```
QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(keyword)
                            .field("th_name" ,2.0f)
                            .field("th_description")
                            .field("th_show_title")
                            .field("content")
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer. I tried it out and it works.

Comment: can you explain your solution? what that "field" means?

Comment: @RoyLeibovitz The field for which you want to match . And since it is a multimatch , you can specify multiple fields.

Comment: @Richa I just want to do it for all fields, without specifying each one of them. I want it to search in all the segment

Comment: @RoyLeibovitz You can just skip the field method and use `QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(keyword)`. As specified here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html, this will default to all fields.

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing, but as I said, it is not working for nested fields.

Comment: May be try with wildcards like `nestedfieldname.*`.  not sure though if it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can use "BoostingQuery"

- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/boosting-query.html
- javadoc : https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/BoostingQueryBuilder.java

Comment: Hey,the links are invalid

Comment: Hi, I didn't understand how this helps me in this case